# Python: Spawn New Minimized Shell

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to to launch a python script from within another python script, but in a minimized console, then return control to the original shell.

I am able to open the required script in a new shell below, but it's not minimized:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import subprocess

pyTivoPath="c:\pyTivo\pyTivo.py"

print "Testing: Open New Console"
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, pyTivoPath], creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

print
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Further, I will need to be able to later remotely KILL this shell from the original script, so I suspect I'll need to be explicit in naming the new process. Correct?

Looking for pointers, please. Thanks!

Note:  python27 is mandatory for this application.  Eventually will also need to work on Mac and Linux.

Comment: are you planning on communicating with the new shell?

Comment: Also why do you need to open a shell?

Comment: pyTivo is intended to be a run as a 3rd party background app to manage the push and pull of media to a TiVo device, via a web browser.  No interaction is required with the originating script I am working with.  The script is intended to provide some granular control/toggles with pyTivo and a couple other helper apps.

Comment: why do you need a shell?

Comment: @Padraic - pyTivo runs within the shell, and must be active/launched prior to gaining access to media and devices via the browser.

Comment: So you basically want to launch a background process?

Comment: OK, you may be right.  I've never interacted with it as a process.  Let me try that path.  - Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to have the other console open? If you now the commands to be sent, then I'd recommend using Popen.communicate(input="Shell commands") and it will automate the process for you.

So you could write something along the lines of:

```
# Commands to pass into subprocess (each command is separated by a newline) 
commands = (
    "command1\n" +
    "command2\n"
)


# Your process
py_process = subprocess.Popen(*yourprocess_here*, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)

# Feed process the needed input
py_process.communicate(input=commands)

# Terminate when finished
py_process.terminate()
```

The code above will execute the process you specify and even send commands but it won't open a new console.